# Flagging post that has multiple questions?

Tags: support, questions, flags, multiple-questions

I was editing some posts and I came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066434/how-would-i-preform-the-tasks-below-in-android-studio), it has 5 questions in total. My Question is, **What flag should I use on posts with multiple questions? Or should I flag at all?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I flag them as should be closed -> too broad.

Comment: in your opinion should I be flagging this users post? I'm asking because I've had a few flags declined and I want to better understand when and why I should flag. thanks

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I would if I were you; in fact I flagged before posting this answer.